# ToolTip for a dropdownlist in .net 4.0

Tags: visual-studio-2010

is it possible for each item in a dropdown list to have its own tooltip?
If so can anyone point me in the direction of an example?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/List_Box_Tool_Tip.aspx)

```
DropDownList1.Items[itemindex].Attributes.Add("title", DropDownList1.Items[itemindex].Text);
```